# Substance L&F not working

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, invokelater, substance

I want to use the [Substance](http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/substance/) L&F library in my Java application, so I downloaded the .jar files and added them to the project classpath. Then I want to set the L&F in the application's `main()` function like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            // Substance
            String skin = "org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceGraphiteAquaLookAndFeel";
            SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin(skin);
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Can't initialize specified look&feel");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

That is done before the JFrame is being created. However, even though no exception is thrown, nothing happens, the GUI is rendered in default Swing L&F.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

**EDIT**
Instead of the `SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin(skin);` call I tried it with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(skin);` instead. This still doesn't work, but at least I get an exception now:

*org.pushingpixels.substance.api.UiThreadingViolationException:

State tracking must be done on Event Dispatch Thread*

Isn't that solved by calling this via `invokeAndWait()`?

**EDIT-2**
Ok, so the problem was something different. The exception was thrown while creating a `JTable`, not when setting the L&F. I was able to solve the issue - the L&F is now correctly rendered - by calling the `JFrame` constructor (which then basically runs the whole application) via `EventQueue.invokeLater()`. But I never did that before, is it "save" (valid in Java terms) to do it that way?

Comment: call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to ensure that it will called in the EventDispatchThread

Comment: @nachokk: I am doing this via `invokeAndWait()`, but even with `invokeLater()` I get the same exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small trick when setting `Substance LaF`. You have to call `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceGraphiteAquaLookAndFeel());` before you call `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceGraphiteAquaLookAndFeel");`. So, set it like this:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceGraphiteAquaLookAndFeel());
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceGraphiteAquaLookAndFeel");    

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                //Your GUI code goes here..
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem as described in EDIT-2 in my OP. Is it valid to do so as described?

Comment: Until you use `invokeLater`, yep.

Comment: not correct `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceGraphiteAquaLookAndFeel());` should be wrapped into invokeLater in all cases

Comment: @mKorbel can you clarify?